# Can't Update and Delete data - SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've just create table and add data to rows. Now I need to delete some rows, but I can't do it using mysql-wokbench. Delete rows is disabled. Also I can't edit data, when I choose "Edita table Data". Can you help me? Why is it so?[image]

**I CAN NOT DELETE BY THE HAND, USING THAT WORKBENCH. BUT I CAN'T  FROM SQL QUERY.**

Comment: Does the user you're logged in as have the ability to `DELETE`?

Comment: please check your user rights...

Comment: p.s can I insert data into tables, using designer? not using SQL commands?

Comment: where is that user rights? I've just installed mysql. I don't know.

Comment: I CAN NOT DELETE BY THE HAND, USING THAT WORKBRENCH. BUT I CANT  FROM SQL QUERY.

Comment: What version of MySQL Workbench do you use? According to this http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=51361 your problem was a bug in version 5.2.16 and probably in some versions before. Try to update to the most latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to edit the result set from a query like `SELECT * from table` the table must have a primary key defined, as this is what WB uses to find a certain record.

Comment: yeas. that's it. Another SQL clients works without primary key too. I was thiking that, WB can the same too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
```

See if you have the rights for that.

Comment: 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO \'root\'@\'localhost\' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD \'*594BDB29093A5.....70F914B05B2D5D02FB5A\' WITH GRANT OPTION'

Comment: Then,its probably a program bug.I recommend HeidiSQL, its open source.

Comment: I ve just install SQuirreL SQL